# How does a single cnn predict bounding box coordinates, objectness score and probability in YOLO?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

In YOLO paper, it is said that a single cnn predicts the coordinates, objectness score and probabilities of the object. I don't understand how this is happening. Can someone explain me that?

Comment: Watch the best yolo algorithm explanation on this course https://www.coursera.org/lecture/convolutional-neural-networks/yolo-algorithm-fF3O0 . Also see the previous video about object detection, it will give you a clear explanation

Comment: Yeah i found the answer. Thank You.